Exercise 3.3.3 (c) of High dimensional probability by Roman Vershynin
I have question Exercise 3.3.3 (c) from Chapter 3.
Exercise 3.3.3 (Rotation invariance). Suppose $ G $ is an $ m \times n $ Gaussian random matrix, i.e., the entries of $ G $ are independent $ N(0,1) $ random variables. Let $ u \in \mathbb{R}^n $ be a fixed unit vector. Then $Gu \sim N(0, I_m).$
question.
If $ G = G^T $, is it still true that $Gu \sim N(0, 1) $? I believe it is not. How should we handle the case of a symmetric $ G $, and is there a similar conclusion we can draw?

Let us first consider the distribution of the components of $G$. All components on the right upper triangle of the matrix are independent $N(0, 1)$. We then have $G_{ij} = G_{ji}$ for any $i, j$. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}(G_{ij}) = 0$ for any $i, j$. For the covariance between $G_{ik}$ and $G_{jl}$, we notice that they are dependent with covariance $1$ either when $(i,k) = (j,l)$ (they are the same component) or when $(i,k) = (l,j)$ (they are symmetric components); and otherwise they are independent and thus have $0$ covariance. To simplify the reasoning, we can consider two cases. If $i = j$, then the two  components need to be the same and we thus necessarily need $k = l$ to have dependence. If $i \neq j$, then dependence requires the components to be symmetric and thus both $i = l$ and $j = k$. More mathematically, this yields
$${\rm\mathbb{C}ov}(G_{ik}, G_{jl}) = \begin{cases}\delta_{kl}, & \text{if } i = j \\ \delta_{il}\delta_{jk}, & \text{if } i \neq j\end{cases}$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, which is defined by
$$\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}1, & \text{if } i = j\\ 0, & \text{if } i \neq j\end{cases}.$$
We will use the property that $\sum_i \delta_{ij} a_i = a_j$ throughout the rest of the reasoning.
All this now allows us to compute the distribution of $(Gu)_i = \sum_k G_{ik} u_k$. First, thanks to linearity of expectations, we directly get
$$\mathbb{E}((Gu)_i) = \sum_k \mathbb{E}(G_{ik}) u_k = \sum_k 0\cdot u_k = 0.$$
By the linearity of covariances, we then get that
$${\rm\mathbb{C}ov}((G u)_i, (G u)_j) = {\rm\mathbb{C}ov}(\sum_k G_{ik} u_k, \sum_l G_{jl} u_l) = \sum_k\sum_l {\rm\mathbb{C}ov}(G_{ik}, G_{jl}) u_k u_l.$$
So, when $i = j$, this yields
$${\rm\mathbb{C}ov}((G u)_i, (G u)_j) = \sum_k\sum_l \delta_{kl} u_k u_l = \sum_k u_k u_k = 1$$
since $u$ is a unit vector.
When $i \neq j$, we get
$${\rm\mathbb{C}ov}((G u)_i, (G u)_j) = \sum_k\sum_l \delta_{il} \delta_{jk} u_k u_l = \sum_k \delta_{jk} u_k  \sum_l \delta_{il}u_l = u_i u_j.$$
Putting everything together, we get $Gu \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ has $1$s on the diagonal, and the off-diagonal terms are the product $u_i u_j$, i.e.
$$\Sigma_{ij} = \begin{cases}1, & \text{if } i = j\\ u_i u_j, & \text{if } i \neq j\end{cases}.$$
Your intuition was therefore correct, $\Sigma$ is not the identity matrix as long as there exists $i\neq j$ such that $u_i \neq 0$ and $u_j \neq 0$ (i.e. when $u$ is not an element of the canonical basis). However, if $u$ is an element of the canonical basis, then $Gu$ is simply one of the columns of $G$, which is therefore not at all impacted by the fact $G$ is symmetric.
